# Sender address vs. SMTP server address

Tags: smtp, dns, sendmail, email-headers

My software (based on LAMP) provides a simple solution for sending email newsletters. What I want is to extend the functionality for this feature.

I have a dedicated server setup at a trusted provider, and my ISP has an SMTP (eg. smtpserver.myisp.com) server I can use. This server has a pretty good reputation (all green on the blacklist checks - eg. http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) :)

My question is:
The email newsletter software is running on one of my servers, and my clients use their own email addresses as the From address - how will all the other mail servers treat an email with this header:

```
From: bill@myclientscompany.com 
but sent through smtp.myisp.com
```

I could use a dedicated domain for all the reply-to and sender address headers in all clients newsletters - eg. campaign.myemailsoftware.com or myemailsoftwarecampaign.com
Example:

Mail headers:

```
From: bill@myclientscompany.com
Reply-to: myclientscompany.something@campaign.myemailsoftware.com
Sender: myclientscompany.something@campaign.myemailsoftware.com
Subject: Lorem ipsum
etc.
```

Would this help, og is there any problems at all?

What DNS configuration will help getting the emails through the filters?
Anyone with experience of using DKIM signatures who will share their wisdom? :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Excellent news that your mail server IP passes the Blacklist Check on our site. However, we wanted to impress upon you that sending bulk mail (newsletters) from your mail server could cause some major problems. For some quick tips on bulk mailing, we'd ask that you check out this post: http://community.mxtoolbox.com/blog/2010/08/27/mxtoolbox-august-2010-sailing-the-email-marketing-seas/

Thanks,
@mxtoolbox